# Compare values within line of file, display line if condition met

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Trying to sort out an issue here. I have a file that includes many lines, but I want to filter for specific line, then compare two values within that line, and if the condition is met, I want to display said line.  This would be done through the entire file.  I'm looking to use a BASH script for this.

Format of line:

```
<timestamp>  <date> : <ServerName> <Device> <In>/<Out> <Value1>/<Value2>
```

Example of line:

```
15:13:33   12/13/19 : Host1  Device1  In/Out 33/34
```

Using this, I want to do the following:

- grep for "In/Out"
- Separate 33 and 34 in variables
- Compare 33 and 34
- If delta between 33 and 34 is more than "X", display entire line to
  STDOUT.

So far, I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

input="logfile.log"

while IFS= read -r line
do
     echo $line
done < "$input"
```

I understand where the `echo $line` is, I could perform commands.  But I'm not sure how to "echo" this and process it within the while loop.

I could do something like:

```
line=`grep "In/Out" logfile.log`
var1=`grep "In/Out" logfile.log | awk -F" " '{ print $7 }' | awk -F/ '{ print $1 }'`
var2=`grep "In/Out" logfile.log | awk -F" " '{ print $7 }' | awk -F/ '{ print $2 }'`

And then compare, the difference, and if met, echo the $line value, but that feels very inefficient.

Any thoughts/input would be greatly appreciated.
```

Comment: Ouch! Three subshells and two pipes per variable assignment? Also avoid using `\`...\`` for *command substitution*, instead use `$(...)`.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder to use $(...) - got so used to the using the other its force of habit.  Need to break that.

By the way, yes, totally agree three subshells is awful.  Unfortunately it does "work" just really sloppy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you try the following:

```
X=3                              # Or assign to whatever
pat="In/Out +([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)"  # Regex pattern to extract the times
while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ $pat ]] && (( ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} - ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} > X )) && echo "$line"
done < "logfile.log"
```

Test sample of `logfile.log`:

```
15:13:33   12/13/19 : Host1  Device1  In/Out 33/34
15:13:33   12/13/19 : Host1  Device1  In/Out 33/36
15:13:33   12/13/19 : Host1  Device1  In/Out 33/38
15:13:33   12/13/19 : Host1  Device1  In/Out 33/40
```

Output:

```
15:13:33   12/13/19 : Host1  Device1  In/Out 33/38
15:13:33   12/13/19 : Host1  Device1  In/Out 33/40
```

**[EDIT]**
According to the OP's info, the regex pattern has been updated:

```
X=3
pat="In/Out +\(([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)"
while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ $pat ]] && (( ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} - ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} > X )) && echo "$line"
done < "logfile.log"
```

Sample input:

```
15:13:33   12/13/19 : Host1  Device1  In/Out (33/34).
15:13:33   12/13/19 : Host1  Device1  In/Out (33/36).
15:13:33   12/13/19 : Host1  Device1  In/Out (33/38).
15:13:33   12/13/19 : Host1  Device1  In/Out (33/40).
```

Output:

```
15:13:33   12/13/19 : Host1  Device1  In/Out (33/38).
15:13:33   12/13/19 : Host1  Device1  In/Out (33/40).
```

The pattern `In/Out +\(([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)` is composed of:

- `In/Out` ... The literal string
- `+` ... One or more whitespace(s) (It may be illegible but there exists a whitespace before the plus sign.)
- `\(` ... A literal left paren
- `([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)` ... One or more digit(s) folowed by a slash and one
  or more digits again. The surrounding parens generate `capture groups`
  and the matched substrings (digits, in this case) are stored in the
  bash variables `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` and `${BASH_REMATCH[2]}` in order.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's also a good approach. Nothing significantly slower than an `awk` implementation there. Would be interesting to test performance difference between `[[ .. =~ .. ]]` with the ERE and `BASH_REMATCH` against a similar `awk` implementation...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you for the comment. I've compared the execution time with the
awk solution using the answer by KamilCuk generating 100,000 line input.
Then the awk solution took approx. 0.2seconds while my bash script took
10seconds. I'd admit bash solution is not efficient in time when handling
with long lines.

Comment: Thank you, tshiono.  This looks to be a good option to start with. To make things a little uglier, I need to add a little more detail here.  The values at the end are enclosed in parentheses and have a trailing period and possibly a space.  As such it looks more like:

`15:13:33 12/13/19 : Host1 Device1 In/Out (33/40). `

What's the easiest way to capture just the 33/40 for comparison? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - based on tshiono's comment, it seems that awk implementation is faster than BASH_REMATCH?  I'm not too worried about speed, but am interested in learning more. Is there another way you would propose this?

Comment: @pdxwarrior Thank you for the prompt feedback. I've updated my answer by modifying the pattern just prepending `\(` to the capture group. Would you please try it?

Comment: @pdxwarrior My pleasure. I've added small explanation for the `pattern` so you can enjoy tweaking it depending on the input. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation too.  I actually did try using the `\(` to include the parentheses, but I actually used a `\(......\)`  - I'm surprised to see that you didn't have to "close" the parentheses.  The actual command line is still a little surprising to me.

`[[ $line =~ $pat ]] && (( ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} - ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} > X )) && echo "$line"`  is saying "pattern matches" and "difference is greater than X" and "echo $line" -- which seems odd, because "echo $line" isn't a condition per se.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It will be more strict to put the closing paren
but not mandatory. As for the `[[ $line =~ $pat ]] && (( ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} - ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} > X )) && echo "$line"`,
it is a shortcut for `if [[ $line =~ $pat ]] && (( ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} - ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} > X )); then echo "$line"; fi`.
Bash command is equivalent to a condition and we can intermix them (by losing a readability). BR.

Comment: The guys who invented shell also invented awk for shell to call when you need to manipulate text. A shell is for manipulating (creating/destroying) files and processes with a language to sequence calls to tools. Just use shell for what it's good at (i.e. that) and the appropriate tools for what they're good at (e.g. awk for manipulating text). See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some of the issues and change `X=3` to `X=3.5` to see another

Answer (score 2):

Such (kind-of-)complicated operations on files are usually done in a single awk script.

```
awk -v X=10000 '
function abs(v) {return v < 0 ? -v : v}
{ 
   if ($6 == "In/Out") {
      split($7, a, "/");
      if (abs(a[1] - a[2]) > X) {
           print
      }
    }
}'
```

The script is almost human readable. First check if 6th field is `In/Out`. If it is, split 7th field on `/`, compute absolute value of the numbers and compare them with delta. If they compare "more than X", print the whole line.

Tested on [repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/RightWorldlyOpensoundsystem). I think you will have to tweak the script to your needs.

Comment: That's a good approach. I would have nixed the function and just incorporated the check and `split` as part of a rule, but there is nothing wrong with the function for reusability.

Comment: A function would be great, but I'll be honest.. I'm still learning scripting. While I get certain things conceptually, I am still a novice.  Not quite sure how to incorporate this to call my file.

Comment: Just `awk ' the script the script' logfile.log`. You can replace all the newlines for spaces and make a cute oneliner.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful as well!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the answer you accepted does what you want, all you need is:

```
awk -F'[[:space:]/]+' '/In\/Out/ && ($NF - $(NF-1)) > 3' file
```

EDIT: given the sample input from  your comment:

```
$ cat file
02:22:50 11/11/19 : Host1 Device1 In/Out 208/219

$ awk -F'[[:space:]/]+' '/In\/Out/ && ($NF - $(NF-1)) > 3' file
02:22:50 11/11/19 : Host1 Device1 In/Out 208/219
```

so if the script doesn't work for you then the most likely cause is you're using a pre-POSIX awk (e.g. nawk or a VERY old version of mawk) that doesn't support character classes. Given  that, try hardcoding the blank and tab instead of `[:space:]`:

```
$ awk -F'[ \t/]+' '/In\/Out/ && ($NF - $(NF-1)) > 3' file
02:22:50 11/11/19 : Host1 Device1 In/Out 208/219
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, always looking to learn more. There's definitely more efficient ways to write code!

I tried the line above and it doesn't work for me, for whatever reason.  Let's say my filename is "myfile" - here's the command I used:

`awk -F'[[:space:]/]+' '/In\/Out/ && ($NF - $(NF-1)) > 3' myfile`

The line in myfile is:

`02:22:50  11/11/19 : Host1  Device1 In/Out 208/219`

Also tried with:

`02:22:50  11/11/19 : Host1  Device1 In/Out (208/219)`

Comment: Putting parentheses around that final field as in your "Also tried with" case would clearly not work since you'd be corrupting what is expected to just be 2 `/`-separated numbers. See the edit I just added to my answer.

Comment: I get that the parentheses could cause it to fail, which is why I tried it both ways.  I don't get any errors, just no return output.  Even using the `[ \t/]` instead.  You are correct, `man awk` shows it is `mawk` and `awk -W version` shows `mawk 1.3.3` - no worries, though. The above bash method is working, so don't feel that you have to spend too much time on this, but know that your willingness to help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The bash version is completely inappropriate and shouldn't be used though. This is simply NOT a job for a shell script. Can you not install a modern version of awk, preferably GNU awk, so you're not stuck hacking around trying to make the wrong approaches work?

Comment: I may have to do that. I'm using a Pi to build some tools for parsing proprietary log files. If I change my environment, it might break it for the other Pi's out there my team travel with. As such, I will probably just need to pick up another Pi so I can update it, test things out to make sure the difference to break something unexpectedly. After that I'll be able to work with them to update theirs.

Comment: Yeah if you're going to be parsing text files you REALLY want to get a modern awk and gawk is by far the most fully featured. I found some documentation that the version of mawk you're using is based on a 1992 version of POSIX (1003.2) so there have been a couple of changes since then!